# AjaxControlToolkit issue in Async WebForms pages

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

There is an issue with AjaxControlToolkit extenders (or any other extenders) in WebForms pages that run Async tasks. If your extender is not visible initially, and you run an async task where you make it visible (e.g. if the visibility should be determined based on the data that you read asynchronously), then you will get the following System.ArgumentException:

```
Extender control '[ControlID]' is not a registered extender control.
Extender controls must be registered using RegisterExtenderControl() before calling RegisterScriptDescriptors().
```

After some analysis, here is what causes this.

1. ExtenderControl base class, which all AjaxControlToolkit extenders
   subclass, calls `ScriptManager.RegisterExtenderControl()` in its
   `OnPreRender` method. Moreover, ScriptManager will throw an exception
   if `RegisterExtenderControl()` is called during any stage other than
   PreRender.
2. For controls that are not visible during the PreRender stage, the
   `OnPreRender` method will not be called, and hence the extender
   control will not be registered.
3. WebForms pages run all async tasks **after the PreRender stage**, and
   before the Render stage. So, if you make your extender visible in
   the async task, then it will not be visible yet in the PreRender
   stage, and only in the Render stage.
4. Finally, extender controls call
   `ScriptManager.RegisterScriptDescriptors()` during the Render stage,
   which throws the above exception due to the control not having been
   registered in the PreRender stage.

Has anyone found a fix or workaround for this?

This seems to be a huge limitation in WebForms, where you cannot effectively use both async tasks and extender controls in the same page.

Below is a sample web page that illustrates this issue.

```
<%@ Page Async="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.UI.Page" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Threading.Tasks" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1" />
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(ReadAsync));
    }

    // Making the panel visible below will result in the following exception:
    // Extender control 'CalendarExtender1' is not a registered extender control.
    // Extender controls must be registered using RegisterExtenderControl() before calling RegisterScriptDescriptors().
    private async Task ReadAsync()
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I posted my reply at https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues/523

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on suggestions posted to this question here
https://forums.asp.net/p/2163988/6293999.aspx?p=True&t=637169211245961059
and here https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues/523, I have come up with a generic way to work around this problem.

Basically, your page would track controls that have extenders and can change their visibility while running in an async task. Then it will make those controls temporarily visible at the proper time on PreRender to avoid the error, and then hide them as needed after the PreRender is complete. The key here is to use the page's new `SetControlVisible` method to set control's visibility.

The full source code for this workaround is posted here: https://github.com/Xomega-Net/XomegaFramework/blob/master/src/Xomega.Framework.Web/Views/WebPage.cs